# Upgrade Current Webstore from Magento EE 1.12 to 1.14 version

Tags: magento, upgrade

We have a Magento Web Store build with Magento Enterprise Edition version 1.12. We are planning to upgrade it to version 1.14. We understand that we will need to do an incremental upgrade i.e. from 1.12 to 1.13 first and then from 1.13 to 1.14. I have a few questions regarding this as below:

1. Is the plan correct about doing incremental upgrade rather than direct to 1.14?
2. We are planning to do the upgrade via Magento Connect rather than manual or through ssh, should that be ok
3. Our store has around 81 extensions including paid/free, some of them we developed, so does this mean it would be more difficult. Note: only a few are customized and most of them are not and compatibility checks already done.
4. If we go for incremental upgrade, does it mean, we have to pay for version 1.13 too?
5. We have identified following steps, does it make sense or any other/better way to do this?

Backup of complete site and DB and create a new instance where upgrade will happen.

List all extensions and details about them like paid/free, customized/not, licenses etc.

Do the following steps on the new instance created for upgradation.

Enable exceptions logging in the system
Flush Magento Cache & disable it.
Making sure all crons are disabled. Make sure built-in compiler is disabled if enabled
Modifying indexers settings to update when scheduled rather than automatic
Complete the Upgrade as per Magento Steps using Magento connect. Deprecation errors may come due to PHP pugradation which needs to be handled
Delete file named maintenance.flag from root
Changing URLs based on changes to 1.13 using URL redirect scripts. [Magento install dir]/php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php - thread-count. thread-count is the number of CPU cores in Magento server, minus 1, to a maximum of 15
Full re-indexing from command line.
   [Magento install dir]/php -f shell/indexer.php — –reindexall
. Make sure to check if all URLs work in this instance

clear [Magento install dir]/var/cache /var/full_page_cache /var/locks
enable crons, enable cache, modify indexer settings and make it default (update when scheduled) and delete the /var directory. If built-in compiler was disabled then re-enable it
Review all extensions one by one and compare functionalities related to each extensions with Live instance and make sure they work as they should on upgraded version
Making sure all custom code is applied to the upgraded version
Verify complete web store functionalities are working

I would appreciate some insight on this. Are we missing anything here?

Comment: You must also check for any core files modification.